# Unwanted symbol gets exported from C++ Win32 EXE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I have made an experiment with a plain Wizard created project (Visual Studio 2013). I wanted to see if I could easily replace the functionality of some known APIs (like [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) with a local app-only effect.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int WINAPI MessageBoxA(HWND p0, LPCSTR p1, LPCSTR p2, UINT p3)
{
    printf("%s\n", p1);

    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "test", 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

After ignoring `user32.lib` in Linker properties. The app builds and runs fine. The console shows **`test`** as expected.

I do get a `warning C4273: 'MessageBoxA' : inconsistent dll linkage` but it can obviously be ignored as the app runs fine.

The peculiarity of the experiment is that [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) now shows `_MessageBoxA@16` as an **exported**(???) symbol from the EXE.

What makes the symbol become exported? I understand that the Windows SDK headers must use `__declspec(dllimport)` and this is creating the inconsistency but surely nobody is using `__declspec(dllexport)` so that the symbol gets exported.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to achieve the same effect without exporting the symbol?

[image]

Comment: Hmya, the compiler previously compiled a declaration for the function in WinUser.h.  It was declared __declspec(dllimport).  Now it encountered a *definition* for the function, completely unexpected since it was previously declared as imported.  Thus the warning.  It now flips the declaration to __declspec(dllexport), the only sensible thing to do.  Thus the export.  If you want to get rid of it then put these functions in their own DLL and link it ahead or instead of user32.lib

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is there a way to do this using static link without the second DLL? It's all an experiment but I wanted to achieve the functionality without visibly linking/importing from external DLL. Perhaps there is a way to get rid of the exports from the EXE in a post-process step?

Comment: What is the point?  Nobody is going to use it.  Got something to hide?